# Multithreading behaviour change when linking a static library to a program

Tags: multithreading, performance, c++11, stdthread

I have been developing an efficient sparse matrix solver that uses the concept of multithreading (C++11 std::thread) for the past year. Doing a stand alone test on my code works perfect and all expectations were exceeded. However, when linking the code (as a static library) to the software I am developing for, the performance was way worse and from what I can see in CPU loads in task manager, all threads are running on the same core which was not the case during the standalone testing. 
Does system loading have anything to do with this ?

I don't have access to the software code.

Anyone has any advice or have any explanation ?

Comment: if all the threads are running on the same core it could be because of `SetProcessAffinityMask()` is called somewhere in the app

Comment: @Slava Zhuyko, the app is written in FORTRAN and SetProcessAffinityMask()  is not supported in that language.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the tradeoffs between a context switch and the actual workload of each thread? This problem could happen if the context switch happens to be more CPU intensive than the actual load each thread is performing. Try increasing the work each thread does and see if the problem gets resolved

Comment: the workload I am using on during my testing is the same in both cases (standalone and with the app). In standalone case I can see up to 80% gain, but with the app the performance is worse than the sequential code.